# Dask dataframe crashes

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm loading a large parquet dataframe using Dask but can't seem to be able to do anything with it without the system crashing on me or getting a million errors and no output.

The data weighs about 165M compressed, or 13G once loaded in pandas (it fits well in the 45G RAM available).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_parquet('data_simulated.parquet')
df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() * 1e-9
# returns 13.09
df.head()
# prints the head of the dataframe properly
```

Instead, if using Dask

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dataframe

client = Client()
# prints: <Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:38576' processes=7 threads=28, memory=48.32 GB>
df = dataframe.read_parquet('data_simulated.parquet')
df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum().compute() * 1e-9
```

prints

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker

[a large traceback]
KilledWorker: ("('series-groupby-sum-chunk-memory_usage-dc8dab46de985e36d76a85bf3abaccbf', 0)", <Worker 'tcp://127.0.0.1:36882', name: 2, memory: 0, processing: 1>)
```

the same happens if I try to do df.head(), df.set_index(...) or any other operation that actually computes anything on the dataframe. I've tried reducing the number workers, such that each has more memory. I've also tried repartitioning the dataframe, but it also fails with the same error. If I set the memory_limit on the client's LocalCluster to zero, the system just fully crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Here's some extra info on the data (gotten from loading it with Pandas)

```
In [2]: print(df.dtypes)                                                                                                            
market_id          uint32
choice_id          uint64
attribute_1          bool
attribute_2          bool
attribute_3          bool
income            float32
is_urban             bool
distance          float32
weight            float32
quarter            uint32
product_id          int64
price             float64
size              float32
share             float32
market_quarter      int64
product_type       object
outside_option      int64
dtype: object

In [3]: print(df.shape)                                                                                                             
(89429613, 17)
```

the object product_type is a string.

Comment: How is your Dask configuration? Did you check [this](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worker.html#memory-management)?

Comment: @PauloMarques I've seen that, and I've tried changing worker configurations, like memory limits, disabling the nanny process, and things like that, but it doesn't help. I can get dask to work if I don't start a client at all, but that defeats the purpose. If I create fewer workers with more memory each, I get messages such as memory usage being to high but there no data assigned to the worker.

Comment: How is your data structured, number of files/row_groups and data types? Have you tried fewer workers, so that each gets more memory?

Comment: @mdurant. I'll add the data structure info as an edit in a minute. I've tried fewer workers (it's written in the post), and it doesn't help. It seems like memory gets piled up and the workers are unable to write it to disc when it gets too large.

Comment: number of files/row_groups

Comment: @mdurant, sorry I thought it was clear from the code that I'm loading a single file. What do you mean by row_groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask works by loading and processing your data chunk-wise. In the case of parquet, the origin of that chunking comes from the datafiles themselves: internally parquet is organised into "row-groups", sets of rows that are meant to be read together.

It sounds like in this case, the entire dataset consists of one row-group in one file. This means that Dask has no opportunity to split the data into chunks; you get one task, which takes the full amount of memory pressure in one worker (probably equal to the total data size plus some temporary values), which has only been allocated a faction of the total system memory. Hence the errors.

Note that you can turn off memory monitoring to prevent workers getting killed in the [configuration](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration-reference.html#worker) or directly with keywords like `memory_limit=0`. In this case, you know that only one worker will be doing the load.

In some very specific situations (no nesting/list/map types), it would be possible to split row-groups, but code for this does not exist, and it would be inefficient due to the compression and encoding of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I'm not sure what is the suggestion. Should I recreate the parquet file such that it's divided by what I intend to use as index? Also, as I wrote in the question, setting memory_limit=0 just makes python crash completely. No exceptions, or messages.

Comment: If you can, yes divide the file

Comment: Ok, I divided the file and now things seem to work. I had to repartition the dataframe after reading because there were too many partitions and things seem to be extremely slow. I got a million warnings, related to this issue: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2801. Thanks for the help!